# Multiple Options in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

There
Im working on a code where i need to pickup two inputs(which are colours) and then get their hex values and send to system as a single line. How can i make this possible with Tkinter.

This is my code as far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


from tkinter import *
import os

clrred = "ff0000"
clrgrn = "00ff00"
clrblu = "0000ff"
clrylw = "ffff00"
clrgld = "ff8c00"
clrcyn = "00ffff"
clrmgt = "ff00ff"
clrwte = "ffffff"
clrblk = "000000"



root = Tk()
root.title("Aura Core")




def StaticColour():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title = "Single Colour Settings"
    
    
    Redbtn = Button(top, text="Red",width="25", command= lambda:os.system("sudo rogauracore single_static "+ clrred)).pack()
    Greenbtn = Button(top, text="Green",width="25", command= lambda:os.system("sudo rogauracore single_static "+clrgrn)).pack()
    Bluebtn = Button(top, text="Blue",width="25",command= lambda:os.system("sudo rogauracore single_static "+clrblu)).pack()
    Yellowbtn = Button(top, text="Yellow",width="25",command= lambda:os.system("sudo rogauracore single_static "+clrylw)).pack()
    Goldbtn = Button(top, text="Gold",width="25",command= lambda:os.system("sudo rogauracore single_static "+clrgld)).pack()
    Cyanbtn = Button(top, text="Cyan",width="25",command= lambda:os.system("sudo rogauracore single_static "+clrcyn)).pack()
    Magentabtn = Button(top, text="Magenta",width="25",command= lambda:os.system("sudo rogauracore single_static "+clrmgt)).pack()
    Whitebtn = Button(top, text="White",width="25",command= lambda:os.system("sudo rogauracore single_static "+clrwte)).pack()
    Offbtn = Button(top, text="Off",width="25",command= lambda:os.system("sudo rogauracore single_static "+clrblk)).pack()



def BrightnessControl():
    
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title = "Choose Brightness Level"

    Onebtn = Button(top, text="1",width="25", command= lambda:os.system("sudo rogauracore brightness 1")).pack()
    Twobtn = Button(top, text="2",width="25", command= lambda:os.system("sudo rogauracore brightness 2")).pack()
    Threebtn = Button(top, text="3",width="25", command= lambda:os.system("sudo rogauracore brightness 3")).pack()


def MultiColor():

    top = Toplevel()
    top.title ="Multi Colour Settings"
    Redbtn = Button(top, text="Red",width="25").pack()
    Greenbtn = Button(top, text="Green",width="25",).pack()
    Bluebtn = Button(top, text="Blue",width="25").pack()
    Yellowbtn = Button(top, text="Yellow",width="25").pack()
    Goldbtn = Button(top, text="Gold",width="25").pack()
    Cyanbtn = Button(top, text="Cyan",width="25").pack()
    Magentabtn = Button(top, text="Magenta",width="25").pack()
    Whitebtn = Button(top, text="White",width="25").pack()
    Offbtn = Button(top, text="Off",width="25").pack()


    

    

ButStat = Button(root, text="Static Colour", width = "25", command = StaticColour ).pack()
ButMulti = Button(root, text="Multiple Colour", width = "25", command=MultiColor).pack()
ButBright = Button(root, text="Brightness Control", width = "25", command= BrightnessControl).pack()
ButQuit = Button(root, text="Quit", width = "25",bg = "#a9a9a9", fg="white", command = root.quit).pack()




root.mainloop()
```

in multicolour if i click red and green then the output should be

`"sudo rogauracore single_breathing " + clrred + " " + clrgrn`

how can i accomplish this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So you are asking how to print a string by clicking a button?

Comment: the very first section has an exampel for it. https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list to store the clicked colors.  If there are two colors in the list, execute the command with the two selected colors.  Then clear the list for next command.

```
def MultiColor():
    colors = []  # store selected colors

    def click(color):
        colors.append(color)
        if len(colors) == 2:
            os.system("sudo rogauracore single_breathing "+" ".join(colors))
            colors.clear()

    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Multi Colour Settings")

    Button(top, text="Red", width="25", command=lambda:click(clrred)).pack()
    Button(top, text="Green", width="25", command=lambda:click(clrgrn)).pack()
    Button(top, text="Blue", width="25", command=lambda:click(clrblu)).pack()
    Button(top, text="Yellow", width="25", command=lambda:click(clrylw)).pack()
    Button(top, text="Gold", width="25", command=lambda:click(clrgld)).pack()
    Button(top, text="Cyan", width="25", command=lambda:click(clrcyn)).pack()
    Button(top, text="Magenta", width="25", command=lambda:click(clrmgt)).pack()
    Button(top, text="White", width="25", command=lambda:click(clrwte)).pack()
    Button(top, text="Off", width="25", command=lambda:click(clrblk)).pack()
```

Comment: I solved it after a few tweaks, I just figured why not have two rows of colors to choose from and also it meant I could use a speed option. I set it so I have 2 variables to store the different colours and a speed variable and pressing a button would assign its respective value. Thanks BTW for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Then try creating a button function in every button using:

```
def click(var):
    global var2
    var2 =+var
    if var2 == 1:
    label = Label(root, text="sudo rogauracore single_breathing " + "red" + " " + 
    "blue").pack()
    var2=0
    if var2 == 2:
    label = Label(root, text="sudo rogauracore single_breathing " + "red" + " " + 
    "black").pack()
    var2=0
      
button = Button(root, text='red', command=lambda:click (0)).pack()
button2 = Button(root, text='blue', command=lambda:click (1)).pack()
button3 = Button(root, text='black', command=lambda:click (2)).pack()
```

Try this, this methods`works only if you click 2 buttons **2 is error**